# Getting out of memory error while using threads for Image loading in Android.

Tags: android

This is my code to take a photo from gallery or camera. I've implemented a background thread to get the task done and then using SmartImageView to set the image using the url. My error is Out of Memory Allocation.:

```
   upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {





                             AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity.this);
                                builder.setMessage("Select") .setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("Gallery", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                           Intent gallIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                                            gallIntent.setType("image/*"); 
                                            startActivityForResult(gallIntent, 10);
                                       }
                                })

                                .setNegativeButton("Camera", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                           Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                                           startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 0);
                                       }
                                   });
                            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                            alert.show();




                    if (bitmap == null) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Please select image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(activity.this, "Uploading",
                                "Please wait...", true);
                        //new ImageUploadTask().execute();
                    }
                }
            });



    }

         protected  void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent data){


             super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);






                switch (requestCode) {
                case 10:
                    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {


                          Thread t = new Thread()
                                  {


                              public void run(){
                        Uri imageUri = data.getData(); 
                     Bitmap b;
                    try {
                        b = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), imageUri);

                        String timestamp = Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis());
                          MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), b, timestamp, timestamp);
                        HttpResponse httpResponse;
                        ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                    b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bao);

                    byte [] ba = bao.toByteArray();
                    int f = 0;
                    String ba1=Base64.encodeToString(ba, f);



                        try {
                            OAuth oAuth = new OAuth(activity.this);
                            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("url");


                            httpPost.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(ba));
                            HttpClient httpClient= new DefaultHttpClient();
                            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                            int responseCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }



                              }};
                              t.start();
                    imgView.setImageUrl(obj.ImageUrl);
                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this

```
 String ba1=Base64.encodeToString(ba, f);
```

is very heavy. I recommend using a http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64OutputStream.html instead, write to a file, then use an InputStream in the HttpEntity.