# bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100, baos) giving me java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, android, performance, base64, android-image

Friends,

I am using this function to decode my bitmap

```
public String BitMapToString(Bitmap bitmap){
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new  ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100, baos);
            byte [] b=baos.toByteArray();
            String temp=null;
            try{
            System.gc();
            temp=Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch(OutOfMemoryError e){
                baos=new  ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,50, baos);
                b=baos.toByteArray();
                temp=Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
                Log.e("EWN", "Out of memory error catched");
            }
            return temp;
      }
```

I got this from a post on SO long back. This is working fine on Nexus, but crashing on Samsung 
phones...I call this in an async task but still its givign me a crash...here is the trace of the exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done in AsyncTask.java on Line 278
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException in FutureTask.java on Line 273
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException in FutureTask.java on Line 124
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun in FutureTask.java on Line 307
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run in FutureTask.java on Line 137
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run in AsyncTask.java on Line 208
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker in ThreadPoolExecutor.java on Line 1076
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run in ThreadPoolExecutor.java on Line 569
at java.lang.Thread.run in Thread.java on Line 856
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at java.lang.String.<init> in String.java on Line 375
at java.lang.String.<init> in String.java on Line 238
at android.util.Base64.encodeToString in Base64.java on Line 456
at com.xxx.xxxx.activity.XXXActivity$SubmitData.BitMapToString in XXXActivity.java on Line 530
at com.xxx.xxxx.activity.XXXActivity$SubmitData.doInBackground in XXXActivity.java on Line 339
at com.xxx.xxxx.activity.XXXActivity$SubmitData.doInBackground in XXXActivity.java on Line 1
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call in AsyncTask.java on Line 264
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun in FutureTask.java on Line 305
... 5 more
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at java.lang.String.<init> in String.java on Line 375
at java.lang.String.<init> in String.java on Line 238
at android.util.Base64.encodeToString in Base64.java on Line 456
at com.xxx.xxxx.activity.XXXActivity$SubmitData.BitMapToString in XXXActivity.java on Line 530
at com.xxx.xxxx.activity.XXXActivity$SubmitData.doInBackground in XXXActivity.java on Line 339
at com.xxx.xxxx.activity.XXXActivity$SubmitData.doInBackground in XXXActivity.java on Line 1
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call in AsyncTask.java on Line 264
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun in FutureTask.java on Line 305
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run in FutureTask.java on Line 137
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run in AsyncTask.java on Line 208
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker in ThreadPoolExecutor.java on Line 1076
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run in ThreadPoolExecutor.java on Line 569
at java.lang.Thread.run in Thread.java on Line 856
```

Comment: Probably your bitmap size is too large as it is filling up your heap space and going out of memory.

Comment: suggestions? thoughts?

Comment: Avoid Base64.encodeBytes() for large image files.
I am not sure what you want to do from the encoded string, the following two links should get you started

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767794/getting-out-of-memory-error-while-using-threads-for-image-loading-in-android

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10159972/how-do-i-decode-a-jpeg-image-encoded-in-base64-in-android-and-see-it-on-an-image/10160856#10160856

Comment: I have to send it to the server....and it only accepts base64 encoded strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a look at Androids Developer documentation on loading large bitmaps and scaling them down before saving them into memory. It may not be the solution you need but i'm sure it can help point you in the right direction.

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Good Luck!